# TFS "source server" (appears to) not work

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, symbol-server, source-server

I am trying to debug a small application that deliberately throws an exception in a dependent library. I built the code for both, but I am debugging on a workstation that I did not use to build the dependent library. I have a step in my small build process to Index Sources and Publish Symbols (using the vNext build system) for the dependent library.

I want to be able to debug and step into the code of the dependent library. My expectation is that the indexing information stamped into the pdb file will allow the acquisition of the source code files "on the fly".

The pdb file successfully uploads to the source server during the vNext build, and the pdb file is successfully loaded from the symbol cache directory I've specified in visual studio according to Debug -> Windows -> Modules.

My application throws an exception deliberately so the debugger will have something to break into. When it does, I see the code that is throwing in the stack trace, so I know the symbols are loading correctly. When I double click on that entry in the stack trace, I am not taken to the source.

Due to the indexing information, I would have expected Visual Studio to get the source, but I am shown a file browse dialog. Note, I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Here is the indexing information in the pdb file (which shows the pdb was indexed correctly):

```
------------------------------------------------
VERSION=3
INDEXVERSION=2
VERCTRL=Team Foundation Server
DATETIME=Thu Mar 08 15:58:40 2018
INDEXER=TFSTB
SRCSRV: variables ------------------------------------------
TFS_EXTRACT_CMD=tf.exe view /version:%var4% /noprompt "$%var3%" /server:%fnvar%(%var2%) /console > %SRCSRVTRG%
TFS_EXTRACT_TARGET=%targ%\%var2%%fnbksl%(%var3%)\%var4%\%fnfile%(%var5%)
SRCSRVVERCTRL=tfs
SRCSRVERRDESC=access
SRCSRVERRVAR=var2
VSTFSSERVER=REDACTED
SRCSRVTRG=%TFS_EXTRACT_TARGET%
SRCSRVCMD=%TFS_EXTRACT_CMD%
SRCSRV: source files ---------------------------------------
C:\Resources\agent\_work\6\s\REDACTED\AppDomainLogger.cs*VSTFSSERVER*/REDACTED/AppDomainLogger.cs*77776*AppDomainLogger.cs
C:\Resources\agent\_work\6\s\REDACTED\CustomLogger.cs*VSTFSSERVER*/REDACTED/CustomLogger.cs*77776*CustomLogger.cs
SRCSRV: end ------------------------------------------------
```

Note, I  have REDACTED some information, it is just pathing information I don't want to reveal, and a server name, but they are correct. If the VSTSSERVER value and source code values are correct, why isn't the source code pulled up when I try to debug. I'm not sure what those numbers are in the source code paths, and I didn't see any login credentials to log into the tfs server. However, since I'm already connected to TFS by virture of using visual studio, I thought perhaps credentials aren't needed? My build process curently does not label source .... could that be part of the problem?

I am a bit new at this (trying to use source information during debugging). Let me know if I'm missing something, and if I am, how I can remedy the situation.

I DO have the Debug -> Options -> General -> Enable Source Server Support checked (and it's two sub-checkboxes) prior to attaching visual studio to the application.